# Does elasticsearch need a persistent storage when deployed on kubernetes?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, persistence

In [the Kubernetes example of Elasticsearch production deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/examples/elasticsearch/production_cluster/README.md), there is a warning about using `emptyDir`, and advises to "be adapted according to your storage needs", which is linked to the documentation of persistent storage on Kubernetes.

Is it better to use a persistent storage, which is an external storage for the node, and so needs (high) I/O over network, or can we deploy a reliable Elasticsearch using multiple data nodes with local `emptyDir` storage?

Context: We're deploying our Kubernetes on commodity hardware, and we prefer not to use SAN for the storage layer (because it doesn't seem like commodity).

Comment: If you don't use an external storage, your data is only host local. You can NFS mount to a well known location, alternatively. Note also that there's a known issue with emptyDir, chowning it to root:root with 750 ACL set.

Comment: It's only local, but the elasticsearch data node talk with other data nodes to maintain another (or more if configured) replica of that data on other pods. And I think (hope) those application-aware communications are more efficient than raw IO synchronization which happens in the NFS scenario, or any other software based storage solution.

Answer (score 6):

The warning is so that folks don't assume that using `emptyDir` provides a persistent storage layer. An `emptyDir` volume will persist as long as the pod is running on the same host. But if the host is replaced or it's disk becomes corrupted, then all data would be lost. Using network mounted storage is one way to work around both of these failure modes. If you want to use replicated storage instead, that works as well.

Comment: But then the network mounted storage becomes a single point of failure. The question is, to make a 99.999% available Elastic-search which is easier: 1. Building a 99.999% available storage, and then using Kubernetes for availability of the service, or 2. Using Kubernetes for availability of a service which knows the lack of HA storage, and do some extra works to replicate its data? (This extra work is coded inside Elasticsearch, so it's just the matter of correct configuration)

Comment: The cluster setup scripts that set up elasticsearch don't create it in a replicated fashion, so without network storage, you have a high probability of losing all of your data. Once you have replicated elasticsearch configured and working, we'd appreciate a pull request describing how you set it up (or better yet, modifying the scripts to make it possible for anyone to do it).

Comment: @RobertBailey it would be amazing if it could shard data by default so there is always a >100% data backup on other k8s nodes if 1 pod/node goes down.